# Django form is not being valid, how to fix it?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am new to Django and I was creating an e-commerce store using Django. I successfully created User Login Form which works perfectly, but I am stuck at User Registration Form. It is not being valid.

***My forms.py:***

```
from django import forms
from django.forms.widgets import PasswordInput

class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)


class UserRegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        data = self.cleaned_data
        password = cleaned_data.get('password')
        password2 = cleaned_data.get('password2')

        if password2 != password:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords must match")

        return data
```

***My register.html***

```
<div>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" name="Register">
    </form>
</div>
```

***My login.html***

```
<div>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" name="Login">
    </form>
</div>
```

***My views.py***

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import UserLoginForm, UserRegistrationForm

# Create your views here.

def userRegistrationPage(request):
    form = UserRegistrationForm()

    context = {
            'form': form
        }

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
            print(username, password)
            
        else:
            print("Form is not valid")

    return render(request, 'index/register.html', context)

def userLoginPage(request):
    form = UserLoginForm()

    context = {
            'form': form
        }

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            print(user)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                # Redirect to a success page.
                return redirect("/")
            else:
                print("Error")

    return render(request, 'index/login.html', context)
```

***My urls.py***

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index-page"), # Home Page
    path('register', views.userRegistrationPage, name='register'), #User Registeration Page
    path('login', views.userLoginPage, name='login'), #User Login Page
]
```

Everytime I visit `localhost:8000/register`, I get the message `Form is not valid` from the if/else condition on form validation in `views.py`. I did similar process with `UserLoginForm` and that is working perfectly.

I tried to work around and had a look into Django Documentation, but I am not getting what is wrong. Can somebody help me why the form is not being valid? What wrong I am doing? Much appreciated.

Comment: Do you fill the form and then submit it in your test?

Comment: Yes, I filled the form and pressed `Submit` button, but no statement executes which are in `if form.is_valid()` condition

Comment: @YasamanShokri also, if I remove the `clean(self)` method from `forms.py`, then `UserRegistrationForm` works perfectly and `if form.is_valid()` condition's body executes.

Comment: seems there is a problem in your clean() function. Try this and tell if it works. password=data.get('password) and password2=data.get('password2')

Comment: @YasamanShokri I finally figured it out that the `clean()` method and `if form.is_valid()` conditions, both are working, it's just `raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords must match")` is not working in a way that it does not print error when I submit different passwords. As I was testing the form with different passwords, that's why my form was not valid because it raised error. When I tested it with same passwords it worked perfectly, but point is how should I raise the error so that it prints the error on the Front-End?

Comment: I don't have any idea. But did you try it without the else statement of your form.is_valid?

Comment: @YasamanShokri I tried that, but it still does not show error on the Front-End.

Comment: You should ask this question separately or just edit your question  and ask the new issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to return the data after validate form with clean method

```
class UserRegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm password',widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        data = self.cleaned_data
        password = cleaned_data.get('password')
        password2 = cleaned_data.get('password2')

        if password2 != password:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords must match")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `looping` format in your `template` file,by rendering fields one by one through loop

Try this:

register.html

```
<form method="POST" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if form.non_field_errors %}
        {% for error in form.non_field_errors  %}
            <span>{{error}}</span>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    {% for field in form  %}
        <div>
            {{field.label_tag}}{{field}}
            {% for error in field.errors  %}
                <span>{{error}}</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <br>
    {% endfor %} 
    <input type="submit" value='Register'>
</form>
```

You need to make changes in your `clean` method which you have defined in `forms.py`.

Make it like this,

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    password = cleaned_data.get("password")
    password2 = cleaned_data.get("password2")

    if password != password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError('password must match')
```

It is already stated in **[django-doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/validation/)**.

> `Note:` Sometimes, it is a problem of server, so make sure you hard refresh your page many times with `Ctrl+f5`.